# How to susbscribe to property on the state in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have `vue` application.

I'm using `vuex` and `vuex-class` packages to connect with the store.

in my component(`vue-property-decorator`) I want to subscribe to some property on the state, and when it change then I want to know.

for example:

my state for example:

```
const state = {
  error: null,
};
```

and getters:

```
 const getters = {
     error(state: any) {
        return state.error;
      },
    };
```

my component:

```
    import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';
    import { namespace } from 'vuex-class';
    const SomeModule = namespace('somemodule');

    @Component({})
    export default class MyPage extends SomeBaseComponent {

    @SomeModule.Getter('error')
    error: any;
     // HOW TO know when error has change?
    }


    onErrorChanged() {

      //?????
    }
```

I want `onErrorChanged` will fire every time the error property on the state changed.

How to do that?

Comment: Is 'onErrorChanged' a function related the the component? Or related to Vuex? If component you could probably use the wacth:{}, if vuex you could call the function from the getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a maintainer of `vue-property-docorator`. Thanks for using the library.

If you'd like to observe the changes of `error` property, you can do it by `$watch`.

As you are using `vue-property-decorator`, `@Watch` decorator is available.

```
@Component({})
export default class MyPage extends SomeBaseComponent {
  @SomeModule.Getter('error')
  error: any;

  @Watch('error')
  onErrorChanged(newErrorVal, oldErrorVal) { }
}
```